# resizer.debug reports "The FreeImage library is not available! All FreeImage plugins will be disabled."

Tags: imageresizer

I've got our Web app running on a dev server, a rented physical server and an Azure VM. The dev and Azure servers are running ImageResizer perfectly, but the rented server on Win2K12 has the following error in resizer.debug:

```
The FreeImage library is not available! All FreeImage plugins will be disabled.
```

I've tried deleting FreeImage.dll and letting it be downloaded, which it is doing successfully, but I still get the error.

I'm really stuck by what might cause this. Is it a permissions problem? And sorry if it's covered in the docs somewhere because I couldn't find it.

Full resizer.debug info below:

```
Diagnostics for ImageResizer 4.2.0 f80bfd38 at xxxxxxx generated 3/29/2019 6:49:54 PM
Please remember to provide this page when contacting support.

---------------------- Licensing OFF -----------------------

You are using a DRM-disabled version of ImageResizer. License enforcement is OFF.
DRM-enabled assemblies (if present) would see <licenses licenseError='Watermark'>

Need to change domains? Get a discounted upgrade to a floating license: https://imageresizing.net/licenses/convert


---------------------- Licensing OFF -----------------------

You are using ImageResizer Performance Edition plugins.

1 issues detected:

(Error):    The FreeImage library is not available! All FreeImage plugins will be disabled.






Configuration:

<resizer>
<clientcache minutes="1440" />
<plugins>
<add name="AutoRotate" />
<add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/cdn/" connectionString="[redacted]" endpoint="xxxxx" />
<add name="DiskCache" />
<add name="DiagnosticJsonPlugin" />
<add name="FreeImageDecoder" downloadNativeDependencies="true" />
<add name="FreeImageEncoder" downloadNativeDependencies="true" />
<add name="PrettyGifs" />
<add name="PsdReader" />
<add name="AnimatedGifs" />
<add name="Watermark" />
<add name="SimpleFilters" />
<add name="WebPEncoder" />
<add name="FFmpeg" downloadNativeDependencies="true" />
</plugins>
<watermarks>
[redacted]
</watermarks>
</resizer>


Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.LicenseDisplay
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.AutoRotate
ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.AzureReader2Plugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Storage.BlobProviderBase]
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache]
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiagnosticJson.DiagnosticJsonPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.FreeImageDecoder.FreeImageDecoderPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.FreeImageEncoder.FreeImageEncoderPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs.PrettyGifs
ImageResizer.Plugins.PsdReader.PsdReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.AnimatedGifs.AnimatedGifs
ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.WatermarkPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.WatermarkPlugin]
ImageResizer.Plugins.SimpleFilters.SimpleFilters
ImageResizer.Plugins.WebPEncoder.WebPEncoderPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.FFmpeg.FFmpegPlugin

Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, diagnosticjson, usepreview, autorotate, page, frame, colors, dither, watermark, filter, s.grayscale, s.overlay, s.shift, s.sepia, s.alpha, s.brightness, s.contrast, s.saturation, s.invert, s.roundcorners, ffmpeg.seconds, ffmpeg.percent, ffmpeg.skipblankframes, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom

Accepted file extensions:

psd, avi, mp4, avchd, flv, fla, swf, mpg, mpeg, mpe, mov, m4v, mkv, wmv, bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi
```

Comment: Make sure the folder has execute permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @LilithRiver but it does already have execute permission.